# BreezeJS datacontext POST in angular turns into 'GET'

Tags: angularjs, post, breeze

I have a factory to retrieve json from my own server via POST, I'm getting the errror "TypeError: Cannot read property '$http' of undefined {query: ctor, stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property '$http' of undefined"}".  Walking through breeze.debug.js I see my request is turned into a GET and thus mungs up the call.  How do I force Breeze to execute my POST?  Below is the datacontext based on the BreezeJS documentation on doing posts at http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/breezeajaxpostjs :

```
angular.module('rmBreezeApp.datacontext', [])

.factory('datacontext', function ($http, breeze, jsonResultsAdapter, logger, model, RMServer,AuthService) {
    breeze.ajaxpost();

    var postData = function (selector, argsArray) {
        return   {"selector": selector, "arguments": argsArray}
    };

    var ds = new breeze.DataService({
        serviceName: RMServer,
        hasServerMetadata: false,
        useJsonp: false,
        jsonResultsAdapter: jsonResultsAdapter
    });

    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({dataService: ds});

    model.initialize(manager.metadataStore);

    return {
        getShiftsForWeek: getShiftsForWeek
    };

    /*** implementation details ***/
    function getShiftsForWeek() {
        var arguments = [];

        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("session?token=" + AuthService.authToken())
            .withParameters({
                $method: 'POST',
                $encoding: 'JSON',
                $data: postData("getShiftsForWeek",[])
            });

        return manager.executeQuery(query).then(
            function (data) {
                return data;
            },
            function (reject) {
                console.log(reject);
            }
        )
    }

});
```

I've got these includes in my index.html

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/breezejs/breeze.debug.js"></script>
<script src="lib/breeze.js.labs/breeze.angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/breeze.js.labs/breeze.ajaxpost.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good thing you wrote a plunker. It revealed a number of errors and opportunities which I'll summarize here.

I [**forked your plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/nhXIG62BDJpEJE77oLFT) and "fixed it". It's now returning data and displaying on screen.

I tried not to change too much but I did re-organize for what seems to me a readable style. I begin by showing the complete application component set at the top:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['breeze.angular'])
    .value('jsonResultsAdapter', createJsonResultsAdapter())
    .service('datacontext', DataContext)
    .service('model', Model)
    .controller('sitesCtrl', SitesCtrl) 
    //.config(configForCORS);
```

### Observations

#### CORS

Your attempt to configure the browser for CORS (`configForCors`) makes no difference to my browsers (IE10, Chrome, FF). I don't think it will help you. Either a browser supports CORS or it doesn't. I haven't found any way around that. You're in trouble if you need to support IE8 because it doesn't do CORS.

#### Configure *ajaxAdapter* for Breeze

The 'breeze.angular' module does that for you. Including that module as a dependency (`angular.module('myApp', ['breeze.angular'])`) and then injecting the 'breeze' service into the first service that needs breeze (e.g., `Datacontext`) is all you needed to do.

#### Configure Breeze for POST queries

Breeze by default sends query requests as GET requests. Your service expects POST requests. Breeze can do that.

You neglected to include the **breeze.ajaxpost.js** library script tag in your **index.html**. You need that Breeze Labs plug-in to make POST queries.

You also have to tell the Angular ajaxAdapter about it. Look in `DataContext#configAjaxAdapter`. You'll see:

```
    // configure that adapter to use ajaxPost plugin
    breeze.ajaxpost(ajaxAdapter);
```

Actually, you don't need to specify the ajax adapter; breeze will enable POST query support for **whatever is the current default ajax adapter *instance*** if you write this:

```
    // configure that adapter to use ajaxPost plugin
    breeze.ajaxpost();
```

But I was more explicit because I had to get the ajax adapter anyway in order to set your default headers:

```
    // default ajax adapter is already a wrapper around current $http
    // as a result of injecting the breeze service.
    var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance("ajax");

    // add the app-specific default headers
    // no need to set "Content-Type" for JSON; breeze does that by default
    ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings = {
      headers: {
          "JsonStub-User-Key": "2d3b6e81-b556-4049-ab54-ec8422237c63",
          "JsonStub-Project-Key": "a753777a-bbff-4db6-8755-ea8c5e60f032"            
      }
    };
```

> Notice I called `getAdapterInstance`, not `initializeAdapterInstance`. We want to modify the existing instance created by `breeze.angular`, not overwrite it with a new one.

#### Client metadata and jsonResultsAdapter

After making those changes, I was getting data from the service. Unfortunately, the
shape of that data didn't quite match the expectations in the `jsonResultsAdapter` or the metadata.

The JSON arrives in an object with a `pathwaySchool` property. That property returns an array. The array contains the entity data of interest; the array itself is useless and should not become a Breeze entityType.

I trained the 'jsonResultsAdapter.visitNode' method to recognize objects with a "buildingCode" property. Such objects contain the data for the `PathwaySchool` entities ... and we say so by returning `{entityType: "PathwaySchool"}` for those nodes.

Patrick's metadata describe a type named "Site". But his jsonResultsAdapter called the type "PathwaySchool". Had to call it one thing or the other. I chose "PathwaySchool".

The metadata also said we should expect an "_id" property that is the entity key. There was no such property in the data. The `buildingCode` property looked most like a unique identifier so I made that property the key. I also added a `name` property so we can display the school on screen.

#### Extracting entities from the ajax results

The service returns a deeply nested object. The datacontext should hide that mess from the ViewModel/Controller.

So the success callback digs in and extracts the array of "PathwaySchool"s.

```
 return data.results[0].pathwaySchool;
```

We should do something if the ajax call fails. The fail callback writes the error to the console (using Angular's `$log` service for future testability) and then re-rejects the error.

Re-rejecting is important!  We want to make sure the caller sees the error so it can process it appropriately. If we did nothing, the Angular would assume we had fixed the error and pass `undefined` to the caller's success callback. That's not what we want. We want to pass the error along to the caller's fail callback. So we re-reject the error and return that (failed) promise.

#### ViewModel/Controller

Patrick's controller called the datacontext and simply assigned the results of the call to the `$scope.sites` array, expecting angular to bind to those results:

```
$scope.sites = datacontext.getSites(); // Not good!
```

That won't work. We don't want Angular to display the promise. We want to set the `$scope.sites` array after the promise resolves with the appropriate entities.

We should also be prepared to display an error if our call for data fails.

Here's how I get the sites into `$scope`:

```
$scope.sites = [];

datacontext.getSites()
    .then(function(sites){
        $scope.error = ''; // clear previous error if any
        $scope.sites = sites;
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        $scope.error = "'getSites' failed: " + error.message +
        ". Check console log for details.";
    });
```

The View can bind to `$scope.error` if there's a problem.

#### View Binding

Finally, we display the results or error on screen. I need a small amount of HTML for the purpose:

```
<div ng-controller="sitesCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="site in sites">#{{site.buildingCode}} {{site.name}}</div>

  <p class="errorMessage" ng-if="error">{{error}}</p>    
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent!  Very clear explanation in the example.  No IE, I'm using Chrome and Firefox.  The CORS headers are a solution I've had to use for a while; perhaps Angular has grown past this problem.  Chrome dev tools confirms I'm making a POST call.  Thanks again!

Comment: Given the effort we both put into this, I'm trut you'll agree to keep this alive and share with others who can benefit from it. I don't know who owns the datasource (http://jsonstub.com). I'm hoping it lives "forever".

Comment: I believe that the service is associated with the `JsonStub...` keys in the headers. If you don't delete the project, all should be well.

Comment: The jsonStub is associated with my (free) account on this free service; I don't know offhand what their usage limits are; since it's a free service I'll put instructions in a pastebin here (http://pastebin.com/dyMGtkBQ) as I can't edit the plunkr; it's pretty easy to setup your own jsonStub account.  This is the kind of answer I'm always looking for; a clear explanation of a bunch of structures and calls from a framework I only just met a week ago.  I hope it helps a lot of other Angular/Breeze users as much as it's helped me.

Comment: Nice. I added this information to the plunker's README.md and also pointed to it from [our "ajaxpost" documentation](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/breezeajaxpostjs). Appreciate your help.

Comment: i noticed the plunker no longer works - is this due to changes in breeze.labs related to angular?

Answer (score 0):

I added [a passing test](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/node/ngDocCode/public/test/server_specs/query_with_post.spec.js) that looks like yours to the [ngDocCode sample](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/node/ngDocCode):

```
var resource = '/breeze/Northwind/CustomersWithFilterOptions?token=1234ABCD';

beforeEach(function () {
    breeze.ajaxpost(); // add POST option to ajax adapter
    em = newEm();      // fresh EntityManager before each test
});
...

it("by CompanyName w/ appended URL query string", function (done) {
    // See SO question
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364078/breezejs-datacontext-post-in-angular-turns-into-get
    var companyName = 'Die Wandernde Kuh';

    // Notice the query string appended to the resource
    EntityQuery.from(resource + '?token=1234ABCD')
        .withParameters({
            $method: 'POST',
            $encoding: 'JSON',
            $data: {
                CompanyName: companyName
            }
        })
        .using(em).execute()
        .then(success)
        .then(done, done);

    function success(data){
        expect(data.results).to.have.length(1);
        var cust = data.results[0];
        expect(cust.CompanyName).to.equal(companyName);
    }
});
```

The request over the network looks like this:

```
POST /breeze/Northwind/CustomersWithFilterOptions?token=1234ABCD HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:58066
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 35
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

The request payload is

```
{"CompanyName":"Die Wandernde Kuh"}
```

I'm not sure what's different between ours and yours. But the ball is in your court to provide a repro (plunker or jsFiddle).

I didn't see anything glaringly obvious in your question's code. I don't know why you're injecting `$http` but that shouldn't hurt.

I don't see where you're taking the dependency on the breeze labs 'breeze.angular' module but you must be doing it somewhere or Angular would have failed ("can't find breezeProvider") when it injected "breeze" into your "datacontext" factory.

Comment: Here's my plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/2Rfzv2KXxJA9ZSVZPA7t?p=preview ; unfortunately I don't have access to the server headers so I can't set CORS, but you can see in the chrome dev tools network log that the request is sent as a 'GET' not a 'POST'

Comment: Here's a pic of my debug tool showing the call as 'GET' - http://tinypic.com/r/2v2xgn5/8